# foreach loop errror in emgu cv using visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, emgucv

I am using emgucv3.2 in my windows form application VS2012. I am following the tutorial http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection (*some of the methods name are different and I have found that!*).

The problem is when I use the foreach loop it throws back error as "foreach statement cannot operate on variable of type 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' ". The code is as follows:

```
    var faces = haar.DetectMultiScale(nextFrame, 1.1, 10,new Size(20,20), 
    new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8))[0];

                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(0,double.MaxValue,0),3);
                }
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var faces = haar.DetectMultiScale(nextFrame, 1.1, 10,new Size(20,20), 
    new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8))[0];
```

to

```
var faces = haar.DetectMultiScale(nextFrame, 1.1, 10,new Size(20,20), 
    new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8));
```